# SpringDataForCassandra: NullPointerEx in Entity when an Int column is set null in DB

Tags: scala, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I'm trying to map my table 'User' to a scala domain Object called UserEntitiy.

An Int column named **CreatedBy** in User table has null values, while calling userRepository.findOne() or .findAll(), I'm encountering a NullPointerException. 

Updating the values of the Int column to any valid Int resolves the issue. However, in our use case, we need to keep nulls in some int columns if there are no values available.

Here's my UserRepository trait, the Entity object, and Controller. 
 
UserRepository.scala

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
trait UserRespository extends CrudRepository[UserEntity, Int] {
}
```

UserEntity.scala

```
import java.util.Date
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.{PrimaryKey, 
PrimaryKeyColumn, Table}

@Table(value="User")
class UserEntity extends Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    var userID: Int = _
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(`type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    var enterpriseID: Int = _
    var createdBy: Int = _
}
```

CoreController.scala

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = Array("/hello"))
@ResponseBody
class CoreController {
    @Autowired
    var userRepository : UserRespository = null
    @GetMapping(Array("/"))
    def getUser(): ResponseBody = {
       var a:UserEntity  = userRepository.findById(4000).get() //NPE Here.
       null
    }
}
```

What I've tried: 
1. Using Options data type for the createdBy column. 
2. Modifying the setter for CreatedBy to set -1 if the value in arg is null. 

 
Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I have removed the [tag:java] tag because there is no Java in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tried out using Option data type, then I highly recommend using Try for handling the error in a functional way

You can rewrite your code as follows

```
import scala.util.Try

val res : Option[UserEntity] = Try{
  userRepository.findById(4000).get()
} match{
  case scala.util.Success(value) => Some(value)
  case scala.util.Failure(exception) => None
}
```